# How to attribuate geolocation permission in cefsharp

Tags: c#, geolocation, cefsharp

I have recently created project based on cefsharp and I want to give permission for geolocation to a site, but idk why my code doesn't work. I got this error :

> CefSharp.DevTools.DevToolsClientException : 'DevTools Client Error
> :Browser context management is not supported.' .

I have don't find anything at this subject.

The code :

```
public async void init(){
            await webBrowser.WaitForInitialLoadAsync();

            using (var devToolsClient = webBrowser.GetDevToolsClient())
            {
                CefSharp.DevTools.Browser.PermissionDescriptor perm = new CefSharp.DevTools.Browser.PermissionDescriptor();
                perm.Name = "geolocation";
                await devToolsClient.Browser.SetPermissionAsync(perm, CefSharp.DevTools.Browser.PermissionSetting.Granted ,"https://www.test.com/") ;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Geolocation is not supported as upstream support was removed. You can mock geolocation as a workaround see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3719#discussioncomment-1383803

Comment: Thank you ! That exactly what I need  , I don't know you can override geolocation function with javascript